# initialized object become null between OnAwake and OnEnable()

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm having a weird issue I don't understand resulting in `null` refrence.

When I try to initialize an object in `OnAwake()` and then use it in `OnEnable()` it is now `null`.

> NULLREFRENCEEXCEPTION: object refrence not set to an instance of an
> object tempMovement.onEnable()

here is the code:

(tempMovement.cs)

```
public class tempMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
   
    temp testing1;

    void onAwake()
    {
        testing1 = new temp();
        testing1.printx();  <-- this works
    }
    private void OnEnable()
    {
        testing1.printx(); <-- doesn't work
    }
}
```

(temp.cs)

```
public class temp 
{

    int x = 5;

    public void printx()
    {
        Debug.LogError(x);
    }
    public temp()
    {
        Debug.LogError("temp init");
    }

}
```

Comment: I have the same issue, did you manage to solve it?

Answer (score 2):

Well I guess this has to do with the fact that your MonoBehavior object has not been created yet.
Take a look at the order: [Order of Execution for Event Functions](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ExecutionOrder.html)

> **Awake**: This function is always called before any Start functions and also just after a prefab
> is instantiated. (If a GameObject is inactive during start up Awake is not called until it is made active.)

> **OnEnable**: (only called if the Object is active): This function is called just after the object is enabled. This happens when a MonoBehaviour instance is created, such as when a level is loaded or a GameObject
> with the script component is instantiated.

I would put the code in OnEnable into the Start method

`void Start() { testing1.printx(); }`